# Stack in C with error "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

Tags: c, pointers, struct, stack

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 5

typedef struct stack{
    int top;
    int info[N];
} stack;

void initStack(stack *s);
void push(stack *s, int val);
void pop(stack *s);
int isFull(stack s);
int isEmpty(stack s);
void printStack(stack *s);

int main(){
    stack *s;
    initStack(&s);
    push(&s, 19);
    push(&s, 2);
    push(&s, 19);
    push(&s, 2);
    push(&s, 19);
    printStack(&s);

    return 0;
}

void initStack(stack *s){
    s->top = -1;
}

void push(stack *s, int val){
    if(isFull(*s) == 0){
        s->top++;
        s->info[s->top] = val;
    } else printf("Stack full!\n");
}

void pop(stack *s){
    if(isEmpty(*s) == 0) s->top--;
    else printf("Stack empty!\n");
}

int isFull(stack s){
    if(s.top == N-1) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int isEmpty(stack s){
    if(s.top == -1) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

void printStack(stack *s){
    for(int i = 0; i < s->top + 1 && i < N; i++)
        printf("%d ", s->info[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I have problems with this code... i think i'm writing out of the stack (index of bound) even if, teorically, I should have positions free. I got the error:

> Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Answer (score 1):

you define

> ```
> void initStack(stack *s){
> ```

but you call

> ```
> stack *s;
> initStack(&s);
> ```

you define

> ```
> void push(stack *s, int val){
> ```

but you call

> ```
> stack *s;
> ...
> push(&s, 19);
> push(&s, 2);
> push(&s, 19);
> push(&s, 2);
> push(&s, 19);
> ```

you define

> ```
> void printStack(stack *s){
> ```

but you call

> ```
>  stack *s;
>  ....
>  printStack(&s);
> ```

All your calls are invalid

Replace

> ```
> stack *s;
> ```

by

```
 stack s;
```

after that, compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
19 2 19 2 19 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

No messages was produced by your compiler when you compiled your version ?

---

You do not use a pointer for *isFull* and *isEmpty(stack s)*, you will have the expected result (supposing you really give a *stack* in argument and not a pointer to a *stack* or something else), but doing that the stack is copied to fill the parameter, this is more expensive than to just get a pointer, so I recommend you to also get a pointer to a *stack* rather than a *stack* and you can also simplify their definition :

```
int isFull(stack * s);
int isEmpty(stack * s);

...

int isFull(stack * s) {
    return (s->top == N-1);
}

int isEmpty(stack * s) {
    return (s.top == -1);
}
```

---

To come back to your initial problem, having :

```
stack s;
stack * p;
stack ** pp;
```

- *s* is a stack, that means a block of memory able to memorize the N+1 *int*
- *p* is a pointer to a stack, that means *p* can memorize the address of a stack, but that pointer is only useful in case it points to an existing stack
- *pp* is a pointer to a pointer to a stack (a double pointer), that means *pp* can memorize the address of a pointer to a stack, but again *pp* is only useful in case it points to an existing pointer to a stack.

adding initialization :

```
stack s;
stack * p = &s;
stack ** pp = &p;

s.top = -1;
```

we have :

- *s.top == -1*
- because *p* point to *s* we have **p == s* and *p->top == -1* (note that  *p->top* and  *(*p).top* are two ways to write exactly the same thing, the "->" is a shortcut making the code more readable)
- because *pp* point to *p* we have **pp == p*, and then ***pp == s* and *(*pp)->top == -1*

In your code a call like *initStack(&s);* gives the address of *s* where *s* values a non initialized pointer to a *stack*, but for *initStack* its argument is a pointer to a valid *stack* and not a pointer to a non initialized pointer to a *stack* => *s->top = -1;* cannot work.

A valid code where *s* is a pointer to a stack and giving *&s* in argument to *initStack* need to be something like that :

```
void initStack(stack ** s){
 (*s)->top = -1;
}

...

stack st;
stack * s = &st;

initStack(&s);
```

but of course this is too complicated for nothing, compare with the code I already given

Comment: thank you... can you explain me the error? Why the other guy is telling me i'm passing a double pointer? Before passing "&s" shouldn't I declare 's' as a pointer? And if I pass only s without ampersand? Hope i got help.. thank u all

Comment: @davide having "_stack *s;_" the type of your variable "*s*" is "_stack *_", so a pointer to a "*stack*". Doing "_&s_" you get the address of  "_s_", so the type of that is "_stack **_" being a double pointer. When you pass "s" without the "&" you pass a pointer to the "stack" but that pointer is not initialized, so it is not a pointer you can use. This is why the right fix is to have "stack s;" and to give its address using "&", "&s" is a pointer  to a valid "stack" being "s"

Comment: @davide I edited my answer to explain more, please look at it

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the address of a stack pointer `s` to stack functions like initStack (i.e. the type passed to initStack, push, etc. is `stack **`).  Changing the declaration of `s` inside `main()` (and only `main()`, not the other functions) to `stack s` will solve your trouble.

If you can find your compiler's warning settings, turn them on.  They will tell you when something like this type mismatch issue occurs.

Comment: yes but Shouldn't I pass to the function a pointer and not a simply struct? I have confusion with pointers... maybe passing &s the parameter is treated like a pointer?

Comment: If you declare `stack s;` then `&s` has type `stack*`, not `stack`. Similarly, if you declare `stack **s;` then `&s` has type `stack***`. Basically, if you use the `&` operator to get the address of a variable, you add a `*` to the type of that variable, and that's what will be passed to the function. Anytime you get the address of a variable, it will result in a pointer.